libeccodes-data update error while upgrading from 23.10 to 24.04
While upgrading my Ubuntu version from 23.1 to 24.04, the installation of the package libeccodes-data failed - while unpacking (2.34.1-1build2) on (2.31.1-1). dpkg could not open
/usr/share/eccodes/definitions/bufr/tables/0/local/8/78/1/codetables/11199.table.dpkg-new

As it did not find the file. I have already tried apt --fix-broken install ; fsck ; and dpkg --configure -a.
Any hint on where to look / what to do to solve this issue?
Thanks.

I have also faced the same issue after upgrading from Ubuntu 23.10 to Ubuntu 24.04. In my case, the issue is resolved after using the following commands.

To remove the problematic package and its dependencies
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge libeccodes-data
$ sudo apt-get autoremove

Update the package list
$ sudo apt-get update

Install the package manually
$ sudo apt-get install libeccodes-data

Install the dependencies of that package
$ sudo apt-get install gnudatalanguage libeccodes0 libgnudatalanguage0


